# Ошибка в 1 день при конвертации UNIX_TIMESTAMP в человеко-читаемый вид

Tags: дата, timestamp, unixtimestamp, mysql

Какая-то магия происходит...
Вытаскиваю дату из mysql,

```
 UNIX_TIMESTAMP(users.birthday) as birthday
```

и вывожу

```
 date("d.m.Y",$row['birthday'])
```

Так вот, все даты, начиная с 1 апреля 2002 года показываются нормально, а 31 марта 2002 года показывается как 30 марта, и все предшествующие даты так же показываются на один день меньше. 
Пробовал использовать и date, и timespamp.
Чтозанах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина бага оказалась в летнем/зимнем времени. Решилась прибавлением к дате в формате timestamp 3600.